# Why do some Unicode combining markers (like \u0BCD) not match [:alpha:] in Ruby?

Tags: regex, ruby, unicode

I'm trying to use Ruby Regexp on Tamil Unicode codepoints. Both `\u0BC0` and `\u0BCD` are combining vowel markers in the `Mark, Nonspacing [Mn]` character category, which per my understanding should match the `[:alpha:]` class. But `\u0BCD` does not seem to match the class.

```
irb(main):002:0> "\u0BAE\u0BC0\u0BA9\u0BCD\u0BA9".scan(/[[:alpha:]]+/).each { |s| puts s.dump }
"\u0BAE\u0BC0\u0BA9"
"\u0BA9"
=> ["மீன", "ன"]
irb(main):003:0>
```

I'm on Ruby 2.6.5p114 on OS X 10.15.2. What could be going on?

Comment: The simplest and most obvious explanation would be a bug in `Regexp`/Onigmo.

Comment: Don't you want `/[[:alpha:]]/`?

Comment: If you want to match any letter + diacritics you should use `/\p{L}\p{M}*+/` and to match one or more, use ``/(?>\p{L}\p{M}*+)+/``

Comment: Searching for "posix :alpha:" shows lots of documentation that `[:alpha:]` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z]` only. What happens if you use the Unicode equivalent `[\p{L}\p{Nl}]`?

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thanks for the pointer. I'll go looking at Onigmo sources.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sadly, this isn't code I control, but deep inside Jekyll. I was trying to find out if this is a bug, and if so, at which layer.

Comment: @theTinMan  it looks like `[:alpha:]` does the right Unicode thing, mostly. I don't believe it's equivalent to `[a-z][A-Z]` except probably in some legacy ASCII-compat mode.

Comment: @theTinMan: [The Ruby documentation for `Regexp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes) does not explicitly spell out what `[[:alpha:]]` matches, but it *does* say that the *POSIX bracket expressions* match non-ASCII characters, and it gives `[[:digit:]]` as an example, saying it matches anything with the Unicode property *Nd*. [The Onigmo documentation](https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo/blob/master/doc/RE) explicitly specifies that `[[:alpha:]]` matches *Letter* or *Mark*.

Comment: Excellent catch. Looks to be a bug then.

Comment: Filed an issue in Onigmo. Thanks @JörgWMittag. If you want to make your comments an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I found a difference between the two: https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=0BC0 says "alnum: Yes, Alphabetic: Yes", whereas https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=0BCD says "alnum: No, Alphabetic: No". So, it looks like `[[:alpha:]]` might be using one of those properties, either exclusively, or in conjunction with *Letter* and *Mark*.

Comment: Aha, thanks! So it may just be a docbug in Onigmo :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two characters in question are (I have marked some interesting things in **bold**):

- [U+0BC0 Tamil **Vowel** Sign II](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=0BC0), with the following (relevant) properties:

  - [*General Category*](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/properties.jsp?a=General_Category#General_Category): [Nonspacing Mark](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=[:General_Category=Nonspacing_Mark:])
  - [*Alphabetic*](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/properties.jsp?a=Alphabetic#Alphabetic): Yes
- [U+0BCD Tamil Sign Virama](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=0BCD), with the following (relevant) properties:

  - [*General Category*](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/properties.jsp?a=General_Category#General_Category): [Nonspacing Mark](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=[:General_Category=Nonspacing_Mark:])
  - [*Alphabetic*](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/properties.jsp?a=Alphabetic#Alphabetic): **No**

The [Ruby documentation for the `Regexp` class](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes) does not explicitly spell out what `[[:alpha:]]` matches, but it does say that the *POSIX bracket expressions* match non-ASCII characters, and it gives `[[:digit:]]` as an example, saying it matches anything with the Unicode property [*Nd (Decimal Number)*](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=[:General_Category=Decimal_Number:]).

While not explicitly documented, it makes sense to equate the `Regexp` *POSIX bracket expression* `[[:alpha:]]` with the Unicode property *Alphabetic*, which would mean that U+0BC0 matches and U+0BCD doesn't.

On the other hand, [the documentation for Onigmo](https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo/) (the `Regexp` engine used in YARV, and mirrored in all other implementations) *does* explicitly specify the workings of `[[:alpha:]]`. In fact, it specifies it in two different places, and they contradict each other:

- In [`doc/RE`](https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo/blob/master/doc/RE), it says that `[[:alpha:]]` matches [*Letter*](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=[:General_Category=Letter:]) | [*Mark*](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=[:General_Category=Mark:]).
- In [`doc/UnicodeProps.txt`](https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo/blob/master/doc/UnicodeProps.txt), it *seems* to imply that `[[:alpha:]]` matches *Alphabetic*.

So, what *seems* to be going on, is that the Unicode Consortium does *not* consider U+0BCD to be alphabetic, and therefore, Onigmo and Ruby do not classify it as `[[:alpha:]]`. In that case, the Onigmo documentation is incorrect, and the Ruby documentation is imprecise.